# How to add a connection point (port) to a cell - jgraphx

Tags: java, swing, graph, jgraphx

I am particularly interested in adding a new connection point to an **edge**, so that it can become a target for another edge.

Comment: Why was this question voted down? I feel confused. I did a lot of research trying to find an answer before asking. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What have you tried?, What error do you get? Asking for guides or howtos is not allowed in this site.

Comment: I created a connection between a vertex and an edge using this method: graph.insertEdge(defaultParent, id, "value", sourceVertex, targetEdge, style)
My user interface updated accordingly and you could see the tip of the edge connected to another edge. This clearly means that a connection is possible between two edges. However, when I try to get the same connection from the user interface (by drag and drop, not by writing code), nothing happens. 
And thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it was voted down either.

The JGraphX [documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html) shows two API methods for adding a connection:

```
    graph.addEdge() 

    graph.insertEdge(parent, id, value, source, target, style)
```

Comment: Yes, I can connect an edge to another edge using the "insertEdge" method, in code. However, I am not able to do this connection in the user interface, by dragging the tip of an edge above another edge and establishing a connection (like you would do with a vertex). I figured that I could implement this behaviour by adding a connection point/port on the edge, but I am not sure how this can be done.